# How to clean occupation list fast?

Tags: r

I need to clean a database with more than 2 million entries on individuals and their occupations. Now, studying the list of unique occupations, I have come across something I need to clean. For example, in the list of occupations you have these variations of descriptions of a HR employee:

```
HR-employee
HR: employee
HR:Employee
HR - employee 
HR : employee
HR employee
```

Now, I need to find a way to get all the entries with the descriptions above to have the description 'HR employee'. And do the same with 2000 other job descriptions. Is there an easy way to have all these 'duplicate job descriptions' merged into just one job description?

Comment: It might be worth a look at the `refinr` package - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/refinr/refinr.pdf

Comment: @AndrewGustar when using the key_collision_merge function of the refinr package, it seems that it does remove half of the possibilities. However, getting back at the original example, it left HR:Employee, HR: employee, and HR : employee. I do not now exactly why it did that.

Comment: It is probably the punctuation characters. You could try removing all non-letters - e.g. `clean_text = stringr::str_remove_all(original_text, "[^\\w\\s]")`. In my experience, however you do it, this is a very difficult task and is unlikely to work perfectly, so you should expect a bit of manual checking/amendment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the variants of "employee" are all preceded by "HR", as in your examples, you can use `str_detect` and `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(job_clean = ifelse(str_detect(job, "(?i)\\bemployee\\b"),
                            "HR Employee",
                            job))
             job       job_clean
1     HR-employee     HR Employee
2    HR: employee     HR Employee
3 ZZ - Unemployed ZZ - Unemployed
4     HR:Employee     HR Employee
5  XY : smth else  XY : smth else
6   HR - employee     HR Employee
7   HR : employee     HR Employee
8     HR employee     HR Employee
```

Note that `(?i)` is used to make th match case-insensitive and `\\b` is a word boundary marker to assert that only the exact word "employee" is matched and not, for example, "employee**s**"

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  job = c("HR-employee", "HR: employee", "ZZ - Unemployed", "HR:Employee", "XY : smth else", "HR - employee", "HR : employee", "HR employee"))
```

**EDIT**:

If there's not only the "HR" category ut also a "Floor" one, then you can do a **nested `ifelse`** operation:

```
df %>%
  mutate(job_clean = ifelse(str_detect(job, "(?i)hr.*\\bemployee\\b"),"HR Employee",
                            ifelse(str_detect(job, "(?i)floor.*\\bemployee\\b"),"Floor Employee", job)))
               job       job_clean
1      HR-employee     HR Employee
2     HR: employee     HR Employee
3  ZZ - Unemployed ZZ - Unemployed
4      HR:Employee     HR Employee
5   XY : smth else  XY : smth else
6    HR - employee     HR Employee
7    HR : employee     HR Employee
8      HR employee     HR Employee
9   Floor employee  Floor Employee
10  Floor-employee  Floor Employee
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  job = c("HR-employee", "HR: employee", "ZZ - Unemployed", "HR:Employee", "XY : smth else", "HR - employee", "HR : employee", "HR employee",
          "Floor employee", "Floor-employee"))
```

Comment: And what if not all employees are preceded by HR? Because there is also a job description called 'floor employee'.